# How to display list of users in a database that are not friends with a particular user

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a system to show all users that are not already friends with a particular user, so that users could only see and add friends which are not their friends already.

But my problem is that code with only remove the user first friend in the add friend list and it will show the rest of friends in the add friend_list which are already his friend.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['em'])){

    $eml = $_SESSION['em'];
    $list = "select friend_id,user_id from friend";
    $friend = mysqli_query($conn,$list);
    $rowf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend);

    $idf = $rowf['friend_id'];
    $id = $rowf['user_id'];

    $query = ("select id,fst,las,uid,pass,email,sts,ocp from Users where email!='$eml' AND  id!='$idf' AND id!='$id'");
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $_SESSION['ids'] = $row['id'];
?>
<table id="list">
<tr>
<td id="id" style=" "><a href=""><?php echo $_SESSION['ids'].'<br>';?></a></td>
<td id="fst" style=""><a href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['fst'].'<br>'; ?>
</a></td>
<td id="las" style=""><?php echo $row['las'].'<br>';?></td>
 <td id="uid" style=" "><?php echo $row['uid'].'<br>';?>
<form action="request.php" method="POST">
  <a href="request.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['ids']; ?>"><input id="request" type="text" value="ADD" readonly></a></form></td>
<td id="email" style=" width:180px;height:40px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['email'].'<br>';?></td>
<td id="sts" style=""><?php echo $row['sts'].'<br>';?></td>
<td id="ocp" style=""><?php echo $row['ocp'].'<br>';?></td>

</tr>
</table>
<?php
 }}}
?>
```

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Small change in your code, please try below. am assuming you are using session variable eml for whom you want to get the users that are not friend with him. you may need to change user_id, friend_id as am not sure which one you are referring as friend.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['em'])){

$eml = $_SESSION['em'];
//$list = "select friend_id,user_id from friend";
//$friend = mysqli_query($conn,$list);
//$rowf = mysqli_fetch_assoc($friend);

//$idf = $rowf['friend_id'];
//$id = $rowf['user_id'];

$query = ("select id,fst,las,uid,pass,email,sts,ocp from Users u where email='$eml' AND  id not in (select friend_id from  friend where user_id=u.id)");
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$_SESSION['ids'] = $row['id'];
?>
<table id="list">
<tr>
<td id="id" style=" "><a href=""><?php echo $_SESSION['ids'].'<br>';?></a></td>
<td id="fst" style=""><a href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $row['uid']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['fst'].'<br>'; ?>
</a></td>
<td id="las" style=""><?php echo $row['las'].'<br>';?></td>
<td id="uid" style=" "><?php echo $row['uid'].'<br>';?>
<form action="request.php" method="POST">
<a href="request.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['ids']; ?>"><input id="request" type="text" value="ADD" readonly></a></form></td>
<td id="email" style=" width:180px;height:40px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $row['email'].'<br>';?></td>
<td id="sts" style=""><?php echo $row['sts'].'<br>';?></td>
<td id="ocp" style=""><?php echo $row['ocp'].'<br>';?></td>

</tr>
</table>
<?php
}}}
?>
```